# can I change my image src back on mouseout in a thumbnail gallery jquery script?

Tags: jquery, image, hover, gallery, thumbnails

I have a photo gallery where the thumbnails change the main large image. It works really well but I want the main image to revert back to the original image once the users mouse moves away from the thumbnails. Is there any way to do that? I've seen lots of similar scripts and tried them but I just can't work it out. Any help would be very gratefully received!

This is what I'm using...

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".thumbs a").hover(function () {
        var largePath = $(this).attr("href");
        var largeAlt = $(this).attr("title");
        $("#largeImg").attr({
            src: largePath,
            alt: largeAlt
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

The images come from a database so I can't give it an explicit filename.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the values of the previous image before you change them.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var oldPath, oldAlt;

    $(".thumbs a").hover(function(){
        var largePath = $(this).attr("href");
        var largeAlt = $(this).attr("title");
        oldPath = $("#largeImg").attr("href");
        oldAlt = $("#largeImg").attr("title");

    $("#largeImg").attr({ src: largePath, alt: largeAlt });
        return false;
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $("#largeImg").attr({ src: oldPath, alt: oldAlt });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've just tried it but no joy. The images change on hover but the main image doesn't revert back. I guess there's a good reason why I couldn't find an example of a gallery that did this.